# Enums and Generics in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, enums

**EDITED**

Hello I trying to make my own Unit Converter

but there is some problem when i try to make both Weight and Length

There are so many duplicated codes

```
enum LengthUnit: String{
    case inch
    case cm
    case m
    case yard

    static func unit(of value: String) -> LengthUnit?{
        switch value {
        case let value where value.contains("inch"):
            return .inch
        case let value where value.contains("cm"):
            return .cm
        case let value where value.contains("m"):
            return .m
        case let value where value.contains("yard"):
            return .yard
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}

enum WeightUnit:String {
    case g
    case kg
    case lb
    case oz

    static func unit(of value: String) -> WeightUnit?{
        switch value {
        case let value where value.contains("g"):
            return .g
        case let value where value.contains("kg"):
            return .kg
        case let value where value.contains("lb"):
            return .lb
        case let value where value.contains("oz"):
            return .oz
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Not only get unit from `String` function but also many associated functions for converting, there are duplicated codes

So I try to implement it by generics but I don't have any idea of it

How can use enums and generics for both Unit types

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you inherit your enums from `String` you're getting `init?(rawValue: String)` parsing initializer for free. Personally, I wouldn't create function like `unit(of:)` because it just throw away the amount part. Instead, I would create parse function like `parse(value: String) -> (Double, LengthUnit)?`

Anyway, if you really want `unit(of:)` function and want to reduce code duplication as much as possible you may indeed benefit from using generics.

First of all, we need `Unit` marker protocol like this

```
protocol UnitProtocol { }
```

Then, we can create generic function which will use `init?(rawValue: String)` of `RawRepresentable` `Unit`s  to return unit based on passed string

```
func getUnit<U: UnitProtocol & RawRepresentable>(of value: String) -> U? where U.RawValue == String {
    // you need better function to split amount and unit parts
    // current allows expressions like "15.6.7.1cm"
    // but that's question for another topic
    let digitsAndDot = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789.")
    let unitPart = String(value.drop(while: { digitsAndDot.contains($0.unicodeScalars.first!) }))
    return U.init(rawValue: unitPart)
}
```

And thats essentially it. If you don't like to use functions and prefer static methods instead, then you just need to add these methods and call `getUnit(of:)` inside

```
enum LengthUnit: String, UnitProtocol {
    case inch
    case cm
    case m
    case yard

    static func unit(of value: String) -> LengthUnit? {
        return getUnit(of: value)
    }
}

enum WeightUnit: String, UnitProtocol {
    case g
    case kg
    case lb
    case oz

    static func unit(of value: String) -> WeightUnit? {
        return getUnit(of: value)
    }
}
```

Or, instead adding `unit(of:)` methods everywhere we may even do better and add extension

```
extension UnitProtocol where Self: RawRepresentable, Self.RawValue == String {
    static func unit(of value: String) -> Self? {
        return getUnit(of: value)
    }
}
```

Now you'll get static `unit(of:)` for free by just adding conformance to `String` and `Unit`

```
enum WeightUnit: String, UnitProtocol {
    case g
    case kg
    case lb
    case oz
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as a one-liner since the raw value of the enum item here is the string version of the enum item, so LengthUnit.inch --> "inch"

```
extension String {
    var lengthUnit: LengthUnit? {
        get {
            return LengthUnit(rawValue:self)
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

Updated version that contains an example of removing the number part of the string. What is the best solution for this is hard to know without knowing what kind of data to expect.

```
extension String {
    var lengthUnit: LengthUnit? {
        get {
            let string = self.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "01234567890."))
           return LengthUnit(rawValue:string)
        }
    }
}
```

*Comment: since you're creating a unit converter you are going to need to split your string into value and unit at some point anyway to be able to perform the conversion so it might be smarter to do that first and use my original version.*

*Comment 2: I don't see how you can possible make use of generics here, your input is always a String and I see no gain in having a function/property return a generics. You could simplify your design using only one `Unit` enum and then only having one `unit` property rather than two*

Comment: As long as "unit case name" is equal to "unit string representation" @DongkunLee

Comment: I edited my question's codes.The input gonna be "15cm" or "15oz" 
I want to eliminate duplicated codes

Comment: Well you can't use `contains` as in your code since for example `15kg` would be converted to `15 WeightUnit.g` so you need to split your string into value and unit, either before or when getting the `unit` property